# I got $S = \bigl\{\tfrac{1}{n}\bigr\}$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$ its limits should be -1, 1, which is not true. Where is the mistake?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Consider set $S = \bigl\{\tfrac{1}{n}\bigr\}$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}$. This makes $S$ an infinite bounded set with bounds $-1$ and $1$. So according to Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem, its limits should be $-1$, $1$, which is not true. Am I making some mistake here?

Edit: By limit points, I mean elements of derived set of $S$.

Comment: How are you applying BW?

Comment: Please let the title specificially represent the question.

Comment: What is a limit of a set ?

Comment: Read the theorem statement carefully. What is your sequence? (Not the set of numbers $S$, but the sequence itself, i.e. the assignment for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ of a number $x_n \in S$)

Comment: @dmh In a book, I have seen a sub theorem under Bolzano–Weierstrass theorem stating "Every infinite bounded set has the greatest and the smallest limit points, i.e. the derived set of an infinite bounded set attains its bounds.". By that logic, -1 and 1 should be in the derived set right because they are bounds of the original set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem says that any infinite bounded set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ has an [accumulation point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accumulation_point), which is not the same thing as a boundary point. Your example has an upper and lower boundary of $\pm 1$ but these are not accumulation points; however $0$ is an accumulation point of $S$ since any open interval containing the origin contains infinitely many points of $S$. It does not violate Bolzano-Weierstrass if the accumulation point lies outside of $S$, it just has to exist.

Comment: In a book, I have seen a sub theorem stating "Every infinite bounded set has the greatest and the smallest limit points, i.e. the derived set of an infinite bounded set attains its bounds.". By that logic, -1 and 1 should be in the derived set right because they are bounds of the original set? Or let me know If there is some gap in understanding.

Comment: The derived set of $S$ consists of only one point, $0$. This is set is bounded above and below by $0$, which is in the set, this example checks out. You are confusing the bounds of the derived set $S'$ being contained in $S'$ with the bounds of $S$ being contained in $S'$; the latter is not necessarily true as your example shows.

Comment: Okay, it is talking about bounds of S', now I am getting this. Thanks for the explanation.